# How to synthesize a new camera view using a stereo pair?

Tags: image, matrix, graphics, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I want to synthesize a virtual view from an arbitrary viewpoint using a stereo pair of cameras that I already have. I have calibrated my stereo rig, so I know both the intrinsics and the extrinsics of the two cameras with respect to each other. My approach for synthesizing the new view is based on the 3x4 camera matrix computation based on `[X, Y, Z]` points computed using depth map obtained from the stereo pair. Then I use multiple point correspondences from the new view `(x, y)` and use the equation `[x y 1]' = C * [X Y Z 1]'` to find out the camera matrix `C`. My questions:

1. Is this the correct approach for generating an arbitrary view?
2. How many point correspondences are recommended and at what planes for computing the camera matrix? As I'm not getting a good result using 6-8 points. I can't use SIFT/SURF because the images are featureless and I have to manually mark the points.
3. Even if I get the camera matrix, how does one do forward warping as the camera matrix is non-invertible.

Please comment if you need more info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answers:

1. No, since you already have a depth map and your rig is calibrated.
2. Irrelevant
3. Irrelevant

All you need to do is build a 3D mesh (actually, a grid) off your depth map. This will have, by definition, no occlusions in either camera of the stereo pair. You can then texture the mesh with the view from either stereo camera (or both, using a more sophisticated texture selection algo based, e.g., on which view is more parallel to each facet so to minimize stretching). You can then render the mesh into any other view you wish.

Comment: Is 3D mesh the only way to do it? How about image-based rendering and 3D warping techniques i.e. which don't require the complete 3D reconstruction. I want to do it in real-time scenarios so the whole 3D mesh generation could be quite expensive.

Comment: Well, do you want "accurate" (in particular, accurate occlusions given your reconstruction), or just "plausible"? Note that, strictly speaking, you do not need a complete mesh topology, just a local adjacency grid, as the depth map is normal to one view (i.e. it is a z = f(x,y) in that view). But in practice some topology problems pop up anyway, because usually you will have holes in the depth map even beside occlusions.